# How can I get the name of connected devices on an Apple AirPort Extreme Base Station?

Tags: wifi, airport

I can see who is connected to my base station by going to Advanced>Logs and Statistics. http://cl.ly/2l0p0w223q1E3T1H0B0w

What I'd like to know is who/what device is connected by device name without having to lookup a table of MAC addresses in a compiled list, etc.

I know that I can filter via MAC address (AirPort>Access Control) and in doing so, run a stricter network. I am more interested at a quick glance to see if Bob's iPhone, Suzy's iPad or HP Printer X is connected.

The AirPort (4th Gen, dual-band, release just prior to the newest one) is running in bridge mode. I'm not sure if this causes any issues with pulling device name or if this is just something that the AirPort does not do by default. I know that when it is not handling DHCP that you cannot create a guest network.

Any third party utilities that I can augment the AirPort with or other suggestions welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got a multi-AirPort network set up, and only the AirPort that handles DHCP will allow me to see names. Under the DHCP Clients tab, there is a column for "Client Name":

[image]

I'd suspect that you're correct in thinking that by running in bridge mode, it won't show this information.

Answer (score 12):

With Airport Utility 6 you find IP, Mac, and network name for WiFi (not ethernet) devices by holding option key, then double click on the AirPort device (e.g. base station) providing DHCP services. You will see a new 'Summary' tab, click outline icon in wireless client list to see details.

Answer (score 3):

Building on Gauzy's answer, you can use his view to see all of your devices.  You'll need to populate the Client ID names when they don't appear or change the existing ones so you can more easily recognize which device is on the network.

Here is the way to assign Client ID names as posted by Bob Timmons:

You can start with your Mac by opening System Preferences and the opening Network. Click on AirPort on the left to highlight it and then click Advanced at the lower right.
Click the TCP/IP tab
Look for the DHCP Client ID area
Type in the name you want. Example, +MacBook Pro Wireless+
Click OK, then click Apply

Open Network back up again and click on Ethernet on the left to to highlight it
Click Advanced at the lower right
Click the TCP/IP tab
Locate the DHCP Client ID area and type in the name you want, +MacBook Pro+, for example
Click OK, then click Apply

Do this for each of your Macs

Your iPhone and iPod will have a similar setup if you poke around on the wireless settings. Not sure about the iPad since I don't have one

You can find a similar setup on most of your AirPort routers by clicking on the device in AirPort Utility and then clicking Manual Setup
Click the Internet icon
Click the TCP/IP tab
Enter the info you want in the DHCP Client ID box

That should get names placed to MAC addresses for most device when you check the DHCP info area.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from Bridge to DHCP under the Advanced tab, in Settings (for Airport device).

Comment: Doesn't this interact with the DHCP server already on the network then? Anyway, can you explain a bit more in detail what that change does and how it answers the question?