# How to find devices on my local network through their IP address

Tags: mac, network

I have a local network powered by a Time Capsule, and connected to 4 or 5 macs. There are other devices on the network too. (Printers, IP Cameras, etc). Is there a way to list the devices on the local network - and their IP addresses?

I've seen this Q/A [How do I know the IP addresses of other computers in my network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19783/how-do-i-know-the-ip-addresses-of-other-computers-in-my-network?rq=1)

but the responses do not show what is what - just a list of IP addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view this in Finder: in the Sidebar, there is a collapsable group called `SHARED` (if you don't see it, Finder > Preferences > Sidebar > SHARED , and ensure that `Bonjour Computers` is checked, but it's probably helpful to check all of them).

To view all detactable network devices, select `All…`.

To get a device's IP address, select it and `Get Info` (`ctrl+click` > `Get Info` or `cmd+i`). Alternatively to find a specific device's IP via Terminal, run `nslookup $hostname`, replacing `$hostname` with the device's name listed in Finder: ex `nslookup foo.yournetwork.com`.

Beyond that, you'd have to log into the router to see what devices are connected (its admin GUI will/should display the device's name next to the IP address it assigned to it).

Comment: Thanks Jacob. The problem is that some of the devices on the router are not known by device - Time Capsule can tell me what Macs are connected, but only the IP addresses and the manufacturer of other devices. But knowing a device is built by Digiboard or Hon Hai doesn't help. I guess if iNet can do it, there must be a way.

Comment: Hi @DavidDelMonte, sorry I didn't get a notification that you'd responded. I'd be very disappointed if a router could/did not know a device's name. The device's name might be called `Device ID`. Look for `DHCP` or `DHCP Clients` (this is what it looks like on an AirPort: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22596/40675)

Comment: No worries. Thanks for responding Jacob. That must be the new Airport Utility. I'm not using that for various reasons (reliability, etc). Inet worked for what I needed.

Comment: Select All??? All-where? Where on the Sidebar is there anything that says All?

Comment: @user51349, `in the Sidebar, there is a collapsable group called SHARED (if you don't see it, Finder > Preferences > Sidebar > SHARED , and ensure that Bonjour Computers is checked, but it's probably helpful to check all of them).`

Answer (score 5):

If you have Android or iOS devices running on the same network, you can install a FREE app called [Fing](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2409870,00.asp) and list all devices connected and their MAC addresses and IPs.

Comment: If it's there, I cannot find it.

Comment: I finally found Fing. It's terrific. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Fing will no longer do everything it used to do, because in IOS, Apple remove the ability to query some details.

Answer (score 2):

There are different way to locate devices on your network :
Netbios traffic / ARP traffic / bonjour traffic / ICMP probes...

Now the most reliable would be to use a good tool such as nmap which is able to perform multiple probes to discover nodes on your network.
You can download nmap for Mac OS here (This isn't the latest version, but it is easier to install this way) :
http://nmap.org/dist/nmap-6.46.dmg

You can then run this script, or paste line after line in the terminal.
Add -sV in the **sudo nmap** command if you want it to be more reliable (but also slower)

```
#!/bin/bash
$i=en1
cidr=$(while read y; do echo ${y%.*}".0/$(m=0; while read -n 1 x && [ $x = f ]; do m=$[m+4]; done < <(ifconfig $i | awk '/mask/             {$4=substr($4,3); print $4}'); echo $m )"; done < <(ifconfig $i | awk '/inet[ ]/{print $2}'))
myip=`ifconfig $i | grep "inet " | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}'`
echo "sudo nmap -n -T4 -PN --exclude $myip $cidr"
sudo nmap -n -T4 -PN --exclude "$myip" "$cidr"
```

Comment: Thanks Florian. nmap requires X-11. I don't want to install X-11 stuff anymore, as 1. my need for it is limited, and 2. I don't know how well X-11 plays with new operating systems.

Comment: Hi David, Zenmap might require X11, but I believe nmap doesn't. It is a command line tool. It is up to you, you can find plenty of network scanner on the market (free and shareware), nmap being the --one of-- best.

Answer (score -3):

I bought this software. It works ok.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36478/inet

Comment: As I asked the question, it seems logical that my purchase answered the question. However, the fact is that this software was only ok, not perfect and I did not give any endorsement, nor should I. I don't appreciate the multiple down votes from an answer I gave two years ago. It will make me less willing to provide help to others. i.e., it's not an incentive.

Comment: I'm just a passerby, not the voter (in fact, I still can't downvote due to rep), but just as the notice says, this answer can still be improved. As of current, you're only linking to a site, which might be down at some time/forever. Aside of the link, there's no info provided at all on the answer (What's the name of the software? How it could help to solve the issue?